# Unable to open any apps on android, getting errors on adb dumpsys

Tags: android

I have a Redmi and upon restarting it just says:

"Wait until your device is fully rebooted before opening apps"

Now I tried doing a dumpsys package and I saw the following exceptions being printed:

```
03/12/21 4:42 pm: Destroying /data/user_de/11/com.logmein.gotowebinar due to: com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Package com.logmein.gotowebinar not installed for user 11

03/12/21 4:42 pm: Destroying /data/user_de/11/com.miui.newmidrive due to: com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Package com.miui.newmidrive not installed for user 11

03/12/21 4:42 pm: Destroying /data/user_de/11/com.android.camera due to: com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Package com.android.camera not installed for user 11

03/12/21 4:42 pm: Destroying /data/user_de/11/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_438907233 due to: com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Package com.google.android.trichromelibrary_438907233 not installed for user 11

03/12/21 4:42 pm: Destroying /data/user_de/11/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_460606133 due to: com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Package com.google.android.trichromelibrary_460606133 not installed for user 11
```

This is basiaclly for all applications available, any suggestions on how can I make this go back to normal ?